# why i'm getting device is not registered for apns error? i have valid certificates for development enviorment

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

why i'm getting device is not registered for apns error?i'm not getting device id 
i have tried following to get deviceid

```
       func application(application: UIApplication, 
          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
    launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
        UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
        UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    var characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")

    var deviceTokenString: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
        .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet)
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "") as String

    println(deviceTokenString)

}
```

is it because of apple error?

Comment: Are you checking in simulator or in real Device?

Comment: thanks for commenting i already fixed you can up-vote :)

Comment: What did you fixed and why should i up vote?

Comment: Please go through all  the comments you will come to know how i fixed, thanks

Comment: Then You should accept @Janesh Post and upvote.

Comment: i can't i just joined this community , i don't have that much of reputation to upvote

Comment: Why not ? that is your question and you can accept and upvote within your question.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added push notification entitlement in `xcode` & App id is registered with push notification.
See screen shot  [image]

Comment: i have already enabled push notification , i think there is some system status issue

Comment: Some tips -
(1)In iPhone settings check weather push notifications enabled for particular application. Or try to reinstall App.
(2)Check with internet connection for receiving push notification, your connection may some website restricted.
let me know, so I can help you more.

Comment: fixed,turn off push notification clean build run, closed xcode. open it again turn on pushnotificaion again clean app and run fixed my issue